# Is there any request.forms in django rest framework same like flask restful?

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

I am facing an error in which when I use form data in angular to send a post request to django rest framework I am receiving data like this:

```
{
  'product_name': ['some'], 'product_price': ['100'], 
  'product_description': ['product_description'], 
  'incremented_by': ['1.0'], 'category_id': ['1'], 
  'sub_category_id': ['2']
}
```

I successfully used form data from angular to flask restful backend service but in django i am recieving as list:

Angular code :

```js
formData.append('product_name',this.formGroup.get('name').value);      
formData.append('product_description',this.formGroup.get('description').value);
formData.append('product_price',this.formGroup.get('price').value);
formData.append('incremented_by',this.formGroup.get('name').value);
formData.append('category_id',this.formGroup.get('name').value);      
formData.append('sub_category_name',this.formGroup.get('subCategoryName').value);
```

Comment: do you have access of the django code? the problem is probably django back-end expetcs a different json format.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response , i found a solution for this . Normally we will get the values from the dictionary using dict["key"] . But using this to get the data returns a list if the data is received as form data from angular or post man . But if we use variable.get("key","") we will get the value.